# Fubinu's principle on series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

If one double series is absolutely convergent then 
$$\sum_{j\geqslant 0}\sum_{i \geqslant 0}a_{ij}=\sum_{i \geqslant  0}\sum_{j \geqslant 0}a_{ij}$$

I looked around and (probably not very good) and found very few proofs. The ones I found had assumptions which I did not see the basis of.

Comment: which assumptions, for example? And what is the intention of mentioning Fubini in your heading? It is true, that such a result follows from Fubini's theorem, do you want to know why this is true? What is your question?

Comment: U would like a proof, yes. So basically an answer to your last question